# how can i make file downloadable in angular?

Tags: angular

I want to make `file` `downloadable` via `url` in my `angular10` app. So for that i do like this

```
<a class="mb-0 op-font-14 font-weight-lighter op-text-primary" target="_blank" [href]="_data?.document?.documentPath" [download]="_data?.document?.documentName">
                    <u>Click to download</u>
</a>
```

But the problem is that it shows file in new tab. But i want to make file downloadable when user clicks on `anchor` tag. How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

I did it by simply making anchor element dynamic. Element will be created on click event nd wil be remved thereafter.
Seems traditional but works great.

```
 startDownloading(data: any) { 
    const url = data.url;
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.setAttribute('style', 'display: none');
    a.href = url;
    a.download = data?.document?.documentName;
    a.click();
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    document.body.removeChild(a);
    a.remove(); // remove the element
  }
```